# lib-boost ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, apple-m1

I wrote a simple code with lib-boost to load a CSV file. After compiling it I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::init()", referenced from:
      boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::mapped_file_source<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, long) in class_map.cpp.o
  "boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::open_impl(boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<boost::iostreams::detail::path> const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::open<boost::iostreams::detail::path>(boost::iostreams::basic_mapped_file_params<boost::iostreams::detail::path> const&) in class_map.cpp.o
  "boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::end() const", referenced from:
      MyMap::loadCSV(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in class_map.cpp.o
  "boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::begin() const", referenced from:
      MyMap::loadCSV(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in class_map.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

I installed boost using homebrew, and it included in cmakelist.

```
Found Boost: /opt/homebrew/lib/cmake/Boost-1.75.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.75.0") found components: system filesystem
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it is a cmake configuration issue. I have to add `iostreams`.

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system iostreams)

target_link_libraries(program pthread z expat bz2 ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```